# SQL Server : multiple queries with Auto ID identity

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that inserts some values to a specific table:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AccessoiresAddOrder
    @AccessoireID int,
    @Qte int,
    @ClientID int,
    @Price Varchar(50),
    @Totalprice Varchar(50),
    @Date DateTime,
    @ValueInt
AS
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accessoires_Orders] ([AccessoireID], [Qte], [ClientID], [Price], [Totalprice],[Date])
    VALUES (@AccessoireID, @Qte, @ClientID, @Price, @Totalprice, @Date)

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[Accessoires_ordervalue] (Value) 
    VALUES (@Value)
```

The `Acccessoires_Orders` table has a column `ID` which is "auto identity". Is there any way to get that value during the procedure execution?

```
int ID = Max(Accessoires_Orders.ID) + 1
```

Why ?

Because this procedure can be executed by multiple users at the same exact time.

Comment: Actually, my answer below was based on the assumption this was SQL Server.  What database are you actually using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either:

```
SELECT @MyNewID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
SELECT @MyNewID = @@IDENTITY
```

SCOPE_IDENTITY() will always give you the value created by the query itself.  @@IDENTITY can give you that value as well, but if a trigger executes after your insert, it will return the ID generated by the trigger instead.

Since you want the ID you created in the query, you'd be best off using SCOPE_IDENTITY().

Comment: Sorry for this late reply but what if i split the Stored procedure to execute one statement and i still want to use SCOPE_IDENTITY() How can i make it refer to an other stored procedure that has been executed before the actual one ?

Comment: You could use it in the other stored procedure, and return that value from the proc.  You can use it multiple times - if you run 5 insert queries and call SCOPE_IDENTITY() after each one, you will get all 5 values.  You just have to store the values somewhere.

Comment: Here's the MSDN article for returning data from a stored procedure:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188655.aspx

Answer (score 0):

After inserting a record to a able with an Identity column, the latest value inserted in the last row will be available in @@Identity variable.

You can select value of @@Identity and return is from your stored procedure. Following is a sample code for that.

```
INSERT INTO Production.Location (Name, CostRate, Availability, ModifiedDate)  
VALUES ('Damaged Goods', 5, 2.5, GETDATE());  
GO  
SELECT @@IDENTITY AS 'Identity';  
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use @@IDENTITY variable that returns you the last identity value returned within the current session - see: [MSDN @@IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187342.aspx). However, if there are e.g. some triggers behind the table you can receive an identity value created by this trigger in a completely different table...

So generally recommended way is to rather use the SCOPE_IDENTITY() - see: [MSDN SCOPE_IDENTITY()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx)